# Split line at character followed by number using Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to split a line after a colon that is followed a number at the beginning of a line:

```
123:[1,2,3].inject(:+) should split to ["123", "[1,2,3].inject(:+)"]
```

This regex will work:

```
(?<=^\d|^\d\d|^\d\d\d):
```

But, if I have numbers with more than three digits, it will fail.

Is there a lookahead to have an arbitrary count of digits preceding the colon similar to a non-capturing look behind?

For example:

```
"123:[1,2,3].inject(:+),456:+c2".split(/,(?=\d+:)/)
```

which will split at commas followed by number followed by colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = "123:[1,2,3].inject(:+)"
arr = str.split(':', 2)
p arr

--output:--
["123", "[1,2,3].inject(:+)"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `\K` feature with ruby 2.0 that removes the part matched on the left from the match result:

```
\d+\K:
```

But since it is supposed to work with only one digit, you can simply do that *(you don't need to check if there is more than one digit before)*:

```
(?<=\d):
```

Comment: ^\d+\K: works but I am still with 1.9. The second one split would split to ["123", "[1,2,3].inject(", "+)"] and therefore doesn't work. But thanks for the Ruby 2.0 solution

Comment: @user2421215: I have tested the first way with version 1.9.3p392 and it doesn't work. I have tested the second way with the same version and it works well. The `\K` feature is not implemented before the version 2.0.0, You can see the Onigmo (the ruby 2.0.0 regex engine) readme file to have a confirmation of this fact: https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo